# Change Product Price as per Radio Button Selection - Magento

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.7, checkout

In an e-commerce website: [utsavfashion.in](http://www.utsavfashion.in/),

There is a custom jquery as displayed following image :
[image: Custom Jquery Extension]

Here, The price changes on every option defined,

And this price must be reflected on Cart as well as checkout page also,

I want to create same functionality as above,
I don't want to use Configurable Products,

I am using Magento 1.7.0.1

How can I achieve this ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Custom Options, it worked for me

Besides,

You can always use "[Custom Options Replicator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-options-replicator.html)" to Copy Custom Options.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with magneto but it should still work ok.. just change your selectors, Please see very basic example of how to total values based on selected checkboxes.. works same way for radio buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/EcHJZ/

```
function updateCosts() {
  var total = 0;

  $.each($('#content input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function(ind, val){
      total += parseInt($.trim($(this).next('.price').html()));
  });

  $('#totalPrice').html(total);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
But it will help me in frontend, But the not for Backend,

But thanks for giving it a try :)

Comment: ya like i said, not familiar with magneto :) no idea what the backend wud look like.